# How can I change the cursor's vertical position with the NodeJS REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Within the node REPL, an multi-line editor mode can be entered by using the command:

```
.editor
```

Well, I can paste multiple lines from the clipboard and execute them. However it doesn't really let me to *edit* any code apart from the last line. The cursor can be moved on that line with the right and left arrow keys, but there doesn't seem to be any ability to move up and down lines to edit them.

Within the NodeJS REPL, how can the cursor be moved vertically?